# How to Extract data or number from button of attribute data-content = " " using Beautiful Soup 4 in python as show below

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
 <button class="btn btn-success phone_number_btn pull-right" data-ad-id="4598214" 
                    data-content="
                 &lt;div class='text-center owner-info-popover'&gt;

                  &lt;div class='primary-lang'&gt;Danish&lt;/div&gt;
                   &lt;h4 style='display:inline-block' class='nomargin mt5 

generic-green primary-
lang'&gt;&lt;i ***class='fa fa-phone'&gt;&lt;/i&gt; 03333315122&lt;/h4&gt;***
                       &lt;p style='margin:10px -15px 0' class='fs12'&gt;Mention PakWheels.com when calling Seller to get a good deal&lt;/p&gt;
                     &lt;/div&gt;
                   " data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-price="4260000" onclick="trackEvents('UsedCars','ContactPhone','Search-Free');
                       adPhoneCount('/used-cars/4598214/increment_phone_count')" rel="popover"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Show Phone No.</button>
```

Comment: You could relatively easily extract the entire value from the 'data-content' using the standard way to access attributes. Once you have the value, you probably should use a regular expression to filter the info you need.

Comment: what did you try? Show your code. And describe problem in question's body, not in title.

Comment: `data-content` is like any other attribute - `id`, `class`, `name`, `href`, `src` - so you can get from elements using the same method `item["data-content"]`. And later you have to use standard string functions or regex. Eventually you may replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `< >` and you will have another HTML which you can use with `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-content` is like any other attribute - `id`, `class`, `name`, `href`, `src` - so you can get it from element using the same method `item["data-content"]`. And later you have to use standard string functions or regex. Eventually you may have to replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `< >` and you will have another `HTML` which you can use with `BeautifulSoup` again.

```
html = '''<button class="btn btn-success phone_number_btn pull-right" data-ad-id="4598214" 
                    data-content="
                 &lt;div class='text-center owner-info-popover'&gt;

                  &lt;div class='primary-lang'&gt;Danish&lt;/div&gt;
                   &lt;h4 style='display:inline-block' class='nomargin mt5 

generic-green primary-
lang'&gt;&lt;i class='fa fa-phone'&gt;&lt;/i&gt; 03333315122&lt;/h4&gt;
                       &lt;p style='margin:10px -15px 0' class='fs12'&gt;Mention PakWheels.com when calling Seller to get a good deal&lt;/p&gt;
                     &lt;/div&gt;
                   " data-html="true" data-placement="bottom" data-price="4260000" onclick="trackEvents('UsedCars','ContactPhone','Search-Free');
                       adPhoneCount('/used-cars/4598214/increment_phone_count')" rel="popover"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Show Phone No.</button>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')

item = soup.find('button')
text = item['data-content']
#print(text)
 
soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')
item = soup.find('h4')
print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```

Result:

```
03333315122
```

Comment: Why you again parsed Html ?

Comment: Please Elaborate it

Comment: `BS` treats `data-content="text with HTML"` as normal string, not HTML, and it doesn't parse it - so I have to get this string and parse it on my own.